# finding equation of tangent line, coming up with a half right answer

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The question is to find the equation of the tangent line at $$(2, 10^{1/4})$$ for $$ y^4=x^3+2x-2$$ I find $$y'= (3x^2+2)/(4y^3)$$, plug that in and find it equal to 0.622. Then, plugging into the point slope formula:
$$y-10^{1/4}=0.622(x-2)$$
then
$$y=0.622x-1.2448+10^{1/4}$$
and finally 
$$y=0.622x+0.533$$
But the answer is supossed to be 
$$y=0.622x-3.11$$
Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Plug $x = 2$ into both putative equations of the tangent line. Look which one gives (approximately) the value $10^{1/4}$. Ponder who made the sign error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have followed the right method. Your answer: $y=0.622x+0.533$ is correct.

Notice, the expected answer:$y=0.622 x-3.11$ is not correct because the given point $(2, 10^{1/4})$ does not satisfy the equation i.e. $(2, 10^{1/4})$ does not lie on the tangent: $y=0.622 x-3.11$